# How to implement FCM push notification in unity for android devices that works even when game is killed

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, plugins

I want to implement Firebase push notification for android games developed in unity3D which works even when game is not running in the background. Experts suggested in many forums that you need to create an android plugin that has the service running always in the background like

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public static String TAG = "PUSH";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("PUSH","FCM Service started");
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
   Log.e("PUSH","Push received");
   UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Canvas", "PushReceived", "This is your push message");
}
}
```

This service will receive the Push notification and notifies the Unity3D game by calling the C# method like this.

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Canvas", "PushReceived", "This is your push message");
```

Then create a .AAR file of this project and place it in \Assets\Plugins\Android.
I followed the same strategy but push never received by unity3D. 
Here is my plugin's manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

This didn't work for me. Then I create another manifest file and place it under assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml and add the service tag in that file as well but this work around went fruitless.

How can I achieve this? I have been trying this for more than a week but no luck yet. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: What about the `Log.e("PUSH","Push received");` log, do you get anything?

Comment: No. I can't see any log.

Comment: Ok. I recommend you put Unity aside for a moment. Open up Android Studio and try to make a fcm notification in it. If you can do it with Android Studio and get it working then copy and use that in your Unity plugin. This is how I make most of my plugins.

Comment: I created one simple application and integrated FCM in it. It was working fine. I sent push notification from FCM console. Then I change gradle file and replace 'application' with 'library' and go to build->build APK. Through this I got .AAR file in build->AAR->app-debug.AAR. I used this .AAR file in another newly created android application. I also placed google-services.json in newly created app and then send the push from FCM console. But still no luck

Comment: Instead of having `android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">`, try to provide the full package name: `android:name="com.company.MyFirebaseMessagingService">`....

Comment: Yes I tried this as well but no luck. Then I tried something which I mentioned in the answer and it starts working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully fixed this issue. There was a difference of my understanding regarding this issue. I was implementing firebase with the library and creating firebase project on the same package of library but the right way was to just have two services `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` and `MyFirebaseMessagingService` in library/plugin and nothing else. Then in another android application or unity game I implemented firebase and created a firebase project on console and in manifest I referenced the services which is in library/plugin/.AAR.

This is how I come over this issue. Now next challenge is that, the service stops when unity app closes.